# Setting buffer specific variables in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to set a buffer-local variable to a global variable if the local variable is not defined using the following autocmd

```
au BufEnter * if !exists('b:Variable') | let b:Variable = g:Variable | endif
```

However, b:Variable is not getting defined. What am I doing incorrect here?

EDIT: To rephrase/clarify, b:Variable is being used in the file. The error is that `b:Variable is not defined`.

Comment: What's the error message? Did you define the `g:Variable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your autocommand is correct. It should work.

I see some reasons why it could fail:

- g:Variable is not defined
- Events are disabled, see :help eventignore  (this is unlikely)
- The autocommand-feature is not supported by your vim version (this is unlikely too). :version must list +autocmd.
- My favorite: The autocommand is not sourced. Are you sure that your autocommand is active?

What does

> :verbose autocmd BufEnter

say? If your autocommand is not listed, it is not active.

Or try something that is simpler and that gives direct feedback to see if autocommands with BufEnter generally work. For example

> :au BufEnter * echom "Buffer Entered"

Comment: Ok, I was actually using b:Variable inside the file and BufEnter is executed **after** the Buffer is entered. Hence, I was getting the errors. What I actually wanted was something along the lines of BufEnterPre. Replaced BufEnter in the autocmd with BufReadPre and now everything is humming along quietly :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `BufReadPre` doesn't cover all the cases - it triggers only for *existing* files, when those are read into the buffer.
To have `autocmd` trigger also for new files, one can compose `BufReadPre` with `BufNew` like this:

```
augroup ale_linters
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNew,BufReadPre * if !exists('b:ale_linters') | let b:ale_linters = 'all' | endif
augroup end
```